# Angularjs ng-view forbidden

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

i have the following routing:

```
  .config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/site/pages/views/Admins/index.php'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }])
```

however in my console i get the following:

```
 GET http://example.com/site/pages/views/Admins/index.php 403 (Forbidden)
```

Can anyone  tell me why this is happening?

I can tell you that i have given rights to both the view and the folder my angular project is to both `Read, Write, Delete`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you got any authentication on server side? It seems like your php code is validating request and returning response with code 403 (probably, not authenticated). What is the result when you paste `http://example.com/site/pages/views/Admins/index.php` in browser?

You can try attach controller, and then in controller make $http.get request and send proper data to backend to authenticate

```
.config(['$routeProvider',
    function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'basetpl.html',
                controller: 'MyController'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });
    }])
```